# VueJs-tinder swiper

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have found this example which looks like the Tinder swiper

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyDan/z9ev725e/21/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=z9ev725e

And now I want to put my own pictures inside this component but if I create an `Array` with pictures and set than the `Array` name inside e.g `v-for="i in images"` and set `<img :src="i.src" />` then the pictures does not appear correctly.

So how can I do that correctly that I see my images from my array?

So I have this code changed:

```
    `<template slot-scope="{data}">
       <div
         class="pic"
         v-for="i in images"
       >
        <img :src="i.src" />
       </div>
    </template>`
```

My `Array`

```
images: [
    { src: 'https://johnnydan.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/vue-tinder/nope-txt.png' },
    { src: 'https://johnnydan.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/vue-tinder/like-txt.png'}
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source of the JSFiddle you provided, the author is using the image url in the `background-image` style. Try changing your snippet to something like:

```
<template slot-scope="{data}">
   <div
     class="pic"
     v-for="i in images"
   >
    <img :style="`background-image:url(${i.src})`" />
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I had a typo in the code, missing a `$`. Not entirely sure if you caught that.

Comment: Can you share how you've defined the array of images?

Comment: Okay yes this is working, but I only see the first image of the array

Comment: You'll need to update the `getData` function that sets up the key with a random number to include your image src there. Rather than changing the `<div>` to do a v-for, leave the code unchanged in the template other than updating the `background-image` style to use `${data.src}` instead of `${data.key}`.

Comment: can you update your answer above with code please, I am too stupid to do that